# can't install mongodb on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to install mongodb by following this [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) (i'm using ubuntu 16.10) I've successfully installed mongodb before but I got an error  so i uninstalled mongodb.

When I try to install it again i got this error when i enter `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` on my terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 255 not upgraded.
Need to get 66,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 269 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-tools
  mongodb-org
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
```

Comment: you may want to ask on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=mongodb+install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instal it with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated mongodb-org
```

but note that it wouldn't authenticate the package that you install.

Keep in mind that Ubuntu 16.10 is not one the supported platforms:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#supported-platforms

See this tutorial for a recommended installation of Mongo on Ubuntu:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

If you installed MongoDB once with the same method you are using right now (the same described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)), your issue could be due to:

1. The **packages key** has been changed and you need to update it; try:

   ```
   sudo apt-key update
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

then install again;

2. You are now behind a **proxy** and apt-get is not working properly when downloading either the packages or the keys.

Hope it helps! :)