# Can't Install MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, installation

I just tried many tips in stackoverflow to solve my issue:

```
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found
```

I try this: [Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092353/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found)

still nothing

I do in this page: [can't install mongodb on ubuntu 16.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930930/cant-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-10)

and still nothing

I do on this page: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

it give me something, then when I update my linux, there are some word about mongodb

when I want to write: udo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

it give this:

```
mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
```

when I do check with

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

how to solve?

I just don't know, hopefully I can install with you advise, and run my code, thanks

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417708/unable-to-install-mongodb-properly-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts?

Comment: it give me: 

Command 'mongo' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mongodb-clients

Comment: I do follow this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178383/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies-mongodb-org

it give me

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
 ocenaudio : Depends: libqt5concurrent5 (>= 5.3.2) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: I guess you fall into this: *"The mongodb package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB Inc. and conflicts with the official mongodb-org package. If you have already installed the mongodb package on your Ubuntu system, you must first uninstall the mongodb package before proceeding with these instructions."*